# Using AJAX returned JSON encoded data in Codeigniter

Tags: json, ajax, codeigniter

I am relatively new to codeigniter. While I was trying to perform a searching operation on my data base using AJAX, The code is returned as successful and the data is retrieved but, This data is JSON encoded and is in the javascript portion of my view so I am unable to use the json_decode function of codeigniter

```
public function lookup(){
    $keyword = $this->input->post('term');
    $data['response'] = 'false'; //Set default response
    $query = $this->MAutocomplete->lookup($keyword); //Search DB
    if( ! empty($query) )
    {
        $data['response'] = 'true'; //Set response
        $data['message'] = array(); //Create array
        foreach( $query as $row )
        {
            $data['message'][] = array( 
                                    'id'=>$row->id,
                                    'value' => $row->firstname,

                                 );  //Add a row to array
        }
    }          
        echo json_encode($data); //echo json string
}
```

the data is accessed in the javascript as data.message.
Please tell me is there anyway i can use this data in the php part of my program

```
<?php
class MAutocomplete extends CI_Model{
function lookup($keyword){
    $this->load->database();
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('Students');
    $this->db->like('firstName',$keyword,'after');
    $query = $this->db->get();    
     // echo '<pre>'; print_r($query->result()); exit;
    return $query->result();
}
}
```

Comment: could you post your model's function?in which format you get result form database?

Comment: @HikmatSijapati I have added the Model code as requested

Comment: see answer hope you solved it.

Comment: What do you mean by saying "Please tell me is there anyway i can use this data in the php part of my program" ?
Please explain your problem further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to parse json response in Ajax's success function using `JSON.parse()`.Like this..

```
$.ajax({
url:'',//your url
dataType:'JSON',
data:'',//your data 
success:function(response){
data = JSON.parse(response);
alert(data.message.value);//alerts value
}
});
```

In controller use `count` rather than empty.To check the array

```
 if( count($query) >0 )
    {
        $data['response'] = 'true'; //Set response
        $data['message'] = array(); //Create array
        foreach( $query as $row )
        {
            $data['message'][] = array( 
                                    'id'=>$row->id,
                                    'value' => $row->firstname,

                                 );  //Add a row to array
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use to response:

```
return $this->output
        ->set_content_type('application/json')
        ->set_output(json_encode($data));
```